# What are easiest way to make slime?

Tags: comfort

What are some easiest way to make slime (especially India)

I have tried with simple glue and water but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with maida and water. You have to adjust the consistency depending upon the purpose. It will be grateful if you could explain the purpose.

Comment: just a simple slime not any purpose

Comment: @justandotherProgrammer this is a hack, we use to stick posters with this mixture, hope this works for you too.

Comment: okay brother will try